# JS: convert 2D matrix into another?

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have a 2D matrix with an -1000 to + 1000 X/Y coordinate system.
For plotting purposes, I want to transform that into another coordinate system, where 0,0 is at the top left.
Any idea how to do that? I know how to do a linear projection of a single axis, but doing that independently yields distortions, especially if the origin matrix is not really rectangular like the target.

Sample data:

```
[{ "type": 2, "x": 201, "y": -201 }, { "type": 2, "x": 201, "y": -200 }, { "type": 2, "x": 201, "y": -199 }]
```

Type here is an information about the nature of the point.

I would have liked to post more code, but I am at a loss how the mathematical operation is called...

Comment: It's not a matrix, it's a list of 2D points. The operation you're looking for is called "translation", and it's very simple: just add the required offset to each coordinate. So `for (const point of points) { point.x += 1000; point.y += 1000; }`

Comment: @Thomas What about non uniform translations? E.g. the original has a width of 200 and a height of 100 and the target has 500*500?

Comment: It's a common thing when working with images, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679287/css-tag-object-fitcover-does-not-crop-clip-videos-in-chrome . Decide which one you want to happen, and also if you need further help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just map all elements adding + 1000 to x and y like this

```js
const data = [{ "type": 2, "x": 201, "y": -201 }, { "type": 2, "x": 201, "y": -200 }, { "type": 2, "x": 201, "y": -199 }]


const dataWithOrigin = data.map(({x, y, ...d}) => ({...d, x: x + 1000, y: y +1000}))

console.log(dataWithOrigin)
```